# context.SaveChanges() method is not saving data in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, razor-pages

I am new to Dotnet and EF. I trying to learn EF. So, I created a to-do app using ASP.NET CORE Web app. Basically it is a Razor page application. I created another Class library project for working with EF. I added the reference to the first project. It is a combination of ASP.NET CORE with EF.
here is the DbContext file.

```
namespace TaskMaster_DataLayer.Models
{
    public class TmDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public TmDbContext() : base()
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Status> Statuses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
        
    }
}
```

And here is the index.cshtml.cs file.

```
namespace TaskMaster.Pages
{
    [BindProperties]
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
        private readonly TmDbContext taskMasterContext;
        
        public List<Status> stsList;

        public Task? task = null;
        public string? TaskValue { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
        public string? StatusName { get; set; }
        public Status status { get; set; }


        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            taskMasterContext = new TmDbContext();
            stsList = taskMasterContext.Statuses.ToList();
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

        public void OnPost()
        {
            TaskValue = Request.Form["Task"];
            if(TaskValue != null && TaskValue != String.Empty)
            {
                foreach(var sts in stsList)
                {
                    var name = sts.GetName();
                    if(name == StatusName)
                    {
                        status = sts;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                task = new Task()
                {
                    Name = TaskValue,
                    DueDate = DueDate,
                    StatusId = status.Id,
                    status = status,
                };
                taskMasterContext.Tasks.Add(task);
                taskMasterContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When Submiting the form the OnPost method is executing. I didn't get any errors but the data is not saving or inserting to the database. The task is added to the DbSet but SaveChanges method is not working. I don't know what I am missing.

anyone help me out. I got so frustrated.

Comment: Are you looking in the right place?

Comment: I also tried to change the state of the entity ... that also doesn't work

Comment: Didn't get you sir @ErikEJ

Comment: *"is not working"* is not a description of a problem. Provide ALL the relevant information. How EXACTLY are you determining that it's not working? What does your connection string look like? If I had to guess, I'd say that you're using a local data file and either looking in the wrong file or else looking in the right file after it's been overwritten with a fresh copy. That's a common problem and probably something that would have come up in searches on this subject.

Comment: `  <add name="TmDbContext" 
    connectionString="data source=FAIRYTALE\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB_TaskMaster;Integrated Security=True;"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"   
    />` This is how my connection string looks like. I used Code first approach. Initial migrations , database creation and seeding data using Up() method in migration file are done successfully. I tried to use Console.WriteLine in OnPost() method  after adding task object to the Tasks property of the DbContext instance it printed all data well but SaveChanges method didn't do anything on the database. @John

Comment: I guess this is entity framework *core* 6?

Comment: From your question, you are using `Asp.Net Core`, But the connect string is the style in .Net framework, I feel very confused about this. Maybe you can follow this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/sql?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you, if you follow the process this will work.

From what you have mentioned you have 2 projects first Asp dotnet core and second ClassLibrary to handle your EfCore.

Now First Goto your Asp proj and open appsettings.json file and add connection string as under:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"defaultCon": "Server= 
(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=TodoDB;Trusted_Connection=True;"
}
```

(you can update your server name if your using SQLEXPRESS you can updated accordingly)
[Connection String Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPmKU.png)

Looking at your models i have created as below two just for example in Class Library:

```
public class Task
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string TaskName { get; set; }
  public Status Status { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int TaskId { get; set; }
   public bool status { get; set; }
}
```

Your DbContext Should be like:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
  public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options): base(options)
  {

  }

  public DbSet<Status> Statuses { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

}
```

Now we have to register AppDbContext in Dependency Injection for that Create class in ClassLibrary proj as below.

```
public static class ServiceRegistration
{
        public static IServiceCollection AddEFServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("defaultCon")));
            return services;
        }
}
```

In Asp proj open startup class and add the extention method we created AddEFServices passing in the Configuration:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddEFServices(Configuration);
}
```

For this example i have used Dotnet Core 5,
Install the below Nuget packages in Class Library:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.17" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.17">
and for Asp proj Install below Nuget Package:
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.17">
```

Now Open 'Package manager console' you can find under(Tools/Nuget Package Manager/Package manager console)
Keep your Asp project as startup Proj and in Package manager console Window Default Project Should be your ClassLibrary

Type Below Command:
Add-Migration InnitialSetup
(If you dont get any errors a migrations class will be created next do below)
Update-Database
(Your Database and tables will be created)

Now Goto your Asp Razor page (IndexModel)
Now in the Constructor you have access to the AppDbContext do as under:

```
private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
    private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;

public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, AppDbContext dbContext)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _dbContext = dbContext;
} 

//For Sample i have hardcoded the data in your case you can receive the data from HTML Form.        
public void OnGet()
{
      var NewTast = new ClassLibrary.Model.Task();
      NewTast.TaskName = "Test Task";
      var Status = new Status();
      Status.status = true;
      NewTast.Status = Status;

      _dbContext.Tasks.Add(NewTast);
      _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now when you check your Database you can see that Table Statuses and Table Tasks will have data inserted in them.